# Unable to contact the Apache Solr server

Tags: search

I followed README.txt and installed these :
apache solr 1.4.1 (Out side WWW Directory)
[Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) Drupal modules
SolrPHPClient r22 (placed inside module)
I copied over xml files(as mentioned in readme) to example folder
And after starting up SOLR as java -jar start.jar I am able to access localhost:8983/solr/admin, 
But still i get

```
Apache Solr: Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server.
```

I am using windows :(

Comment: I'd be curious if you resolved this and how.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're able to connect to ApacheSolr I am keen to know if you set the credentials correctly on Drupal side. Make sure that you added the local server correctly here `admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/add`. After that use the `Test connection` button to verify that you are able to contact the ApacheSolr server.